# What is the actual difference between sh and bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

Based on what I've read online, `sh` is essentially an alias for `bash`; running a shellscript with `sh` will behave the same as if it's run with `bash`.

In my experience this is not entirely true, as newlines are processed differently. What exactly is the difference between `sh` and `bash`, and as `zsh` is now the default shell does anyone know if `sh` will change in future versions of Mac OS?

Consider the following code:

```
sh -c "echo \"Hello\nWorld\""
```

This should produce the following output:

```
Hello
World
```

However when run with `bash`:

```
bash -c "echo \"Hello\nWorld\""
```

The newline is not output:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3439894 Under BigSur `/bin/sh` is just a wrapper which executes the shell `/var/select/sh` points to (which in my case is `bash`), see `man sh` for details.

Comment: It might be the same already for Catalina, run `strings /bin/sh` to check.

Answer (score 4):

The long answer on this has already been written, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash.

The `echo` builtin is one (of several) things where `sh` and `bash` differ. To get `bash` to handle `\n` as a control character use `echo -e`.

```
$ bash -c "echo -e \"Hello\nWorld\""
Hello
World
```

As for the definition of `sh` on macOS, see `man sh` (e.g. on Big Sur):

```
sh is a POSIX-compliant command interpreter (shell).  It is implemented by re-execing as 
either bash(1), dash(1), or zsh(1) as determined by the symbolic link located at 
/private/var/select/sh. If /private/var/select/sh does not exist or does not point to a
valid shell, sh will use one of the supported shells.
```

So basically executing `sh` will execute whichever shell `/private/var/select/sh` points to in "sh/POSIX compatibility mode".

Comment: Thank you very much. That's certainly given me some clarification, but `/private/var/select/sh` does not seem to exist for me. `sh --version` outputs `GNU bash`, so it must be linking to `bash`.

What I'd like is a way for my current shellscripts, without modification, to run through `bash` and behave as they do with `sh`. I've tried the `--posix` argument but that's not making any difference. The reason I want to do this is it sounds like the `sh` may be fundamentally different across machines. Maybe what I want to achieve isn't possible without modifying my scripts.

Comment: @BenCheshire `sh` **must** behave the same for all systems adhering to POSIX/the Unix standard. So as long as you use `#!/bin/sh` the script should work on all Unix systems. It also doesn't matter whether `/bin/sh` is a binary on its own or just linked to `bash`, `zsh` etc. Running either as `sh` will ensure sh compatibility and turn off any shell-specific functions.

Comment: Interesting. That should save me a lot of bother. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/1088558) explains it quite nicely, actually.